# Error when "import tensorflow as tf" in colab

Tags: tensorflow

When I "import tensorflow as tf" in google colab I am getting the following error. Any idea how to fix it ?

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-07e0f991eb97> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/pywrap_tf_session.py in <module>()
     17 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
     18 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
---> 19 from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import *
     20 from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import _TF_SetTarget
     21 from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import _TF_SetConfig

ImportError: SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at 0x7f79368db0a0> returned a result with an error set

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed now in 2.8.0 stable version. If it still persists ,please install Numpy 1.21.5 manually and  Try again.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. I've installed tensorflow==2.8 and numpy==1.21.5, seems the issue still exits. I'm also running in colab but with local runtime. Could you pls help? @tensorflow-support

Answer (score 0):

I've post a similar error on tensorflow github issue.

[Tensorflow 2.8.0 | Error Message: ImportError: SystemError.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/55440#issue-1186928438)

My solution (since I'm using conda environment on Windows 10), is to **downgrade the Tensorflow version** to 2.7.0. Hope help helps.

Comment: **UPDATE (March, 31st 2022):**

My issue is solved. For me, other than downgrade the tensorflow version (to 2.7.0?), since I'm using **anaconda venv** on Windows 10, I **upgrade the python version**.
Hope it helps.